# Elementor Image carousel scroll

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Is there any way to change the images on the image carousel widget(elementor) via scroll?

I want to make an image carousel sticky on top and as I scroll down to change images of the carousel gallery.

I use Elementor pro andWordPresss on latest updates

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.